# “yo jhipster:entity” with one-to-one relationship does not create entity

Tags: jhipster

I tried to add entity "blog" with relation one-to-one to fresh jhipster's project, but no results, jhipster generator did not add the entity "blog" to my project

```
$ yo jhipster:entity blog

The entity blog is being created.


  Generating field #1

? Do you want to add a field to your entity? Yes
? What is the name of your field? name
? What is the type of your field? String
? Do you want to add validation rules to your field? No

================= Blog =================
Fields
name (String)


Generating field #2

? Do you want to add a field to your entity? No

================= Blog =================
Fields
name (String)


Generating relationships to other entities

? Do you want to add a relationship to another entity? Yes
? What is the name of the other entity? user
? What is the name of the relationship? user
? What is the type of the relationship? one-to-one
? Is this entity the owner of the relationship? Yes
? When you display this relationship with AngularJS, which field from 'user' do you want to use? id
? Do you want to add any validation rules to this relationship? No

================= Blog =================
Fields
name (String)

Relationships
user (User) one-to-one


Generating relationships to other entities

? Do you want to add a relationship to another entity? No

================= Blog =================
Fields
name (String)

Relationships
user (User) one-to-one



? Do you want to use a Data Transfer Object (DTO)? No, use the entity directly
? Do you want to use separate service class for your business logic? No, the REST controller should use the repository directly
? Do you want pagination on your entity? No

Everything is configured, generating the entity...
$
```

no error message, nothing.
I tried add same entity by JDL - same result.

```
$ yo jhipster:import-jdl jhipster-jdl.jh
The jdl is being imported.
$
```

file jhipster-jdl.jh:

```
entity Blog {
    name String
}

relationship OneToOne {
    Blog{User} to User
}
```

ver JHipster Generator v3.4.2

Workaround this problem - make 2 step :

1. create entity without any relationship
2. add desired relation one-to-one

Comment: What result do you expect?

Comment: I expected the jhipster generator to add my entitty "blog" to project, but it did not.

Comment: I have reproduced it, it loks like a regression, please post an issue in github.

Comment: I opened issue https://github.com/jhipster/generator-jhipster/issues/3773

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this is a bug, 
[see opened issue on GitHub](https://github.com/jhipster/generator-jhipster/issues/3773)